# Woocommerce - Hide shop for unregistered user

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce web site and I would like to hide the shop when the user in not logged. I put this code in the file ! archive-product.php which is in my template 'twentytwelve-child' in a woocommerce folder.

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

auth_redirect();

get_header( 'shop' ); ?>
```

Normaly the 'auth_redirect()' have to redirected me in the login page, but it just doesn't work.

I tried also with this code but it does not work also.

```
$login = is_user_logged_in();
if ($login == FALSE ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url() ); 
    exit;
}
```

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to modify Woocommerce template file for what you are trying to achieve. Just add the following code to functions.php

```
function custom_redirect() {        
    if( is_shop() && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() ); 
        exit();
    }   
}

add_action("template_redirect","custom_redirect");
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks you. I also add some other features which can be helpful.

```
// Redirect none registered users to a login page
function custom_redirect() {        
    if( (is_shop() || is_product() || is_product_category() )  && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( site_url( '/mon-compte' ) );
        exit();
    }   
}
add_action("template_redirect","custom_redirect");
```